# Can someone explain this "Longest Common Subsequence" algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, diff, subsequence, string-algorithm

The `Longest Common Subsequence (LCS)` problem is: given two sequences `A` and `B`, find the longest subsequence that is found both in `A` and in `B`. For example, given `A = "peterparker"` and `B = "spiderman"`, the longest common subsequence is `"pera"`.

Can someone explain this `Longest Common Subsequence` algorithm?

```
def longestCommonSubsequence(A: List, B: List) -> int:
    # n = len(A)
    # m = len(B)
    
    indeces_A = collections.defaultdict(list)
    
    # O(n)
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        indeces_A[a].append(i)
    
    # O(n)
    for indeces_a in indeces_A.values():
        indeces_a.reverse()
    
    # O(m)
    indeces_A_filtered = []
    for b in B:
        indeces_A_filtered.extend(indeces_A[b])
    
    # The length of indeces_A_filtered is at most n*m, but in practice it's more like O(m) or O(n) as far as I can tell.
    iAs = []
    # O(m log m) in practice as far as I can tell.
    for iA in indeces_A_filtered:
        j = bisect.bisect_left(iAs, iA)
        if j == len(iAs):
            iAs.append(iA)
        else:
            iAs[j] = iA
    return len(iAs)
```

The algorithm as written finds the length of the `longest common subsequence`, but can be modified to find the `longest common subsequence` outright.

I found this algorithm as I was looking at the fastest python solutions to an equivalent problem on leetcode [link](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/455683856/). This algorithm was the fastest python solution (40 ms) for the problem and it also seems to have `O(m log m)` time complexity, which is much better than the `O(m*n)` time complexity of most other solutions.

I do not fully understand why it works and tried looking all over for known algorithms to the `Longest Common Subsequence` problem to find other mentions of it, but couldn't find anything like it. The closest thing I could find was the `Hunt–Szymanski algorithm` [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93Szymanski_algorithm) which is also said to have `O(m log m)` in practice, but does not seem to be the same algorithm.

What I kind of understand:

1. `indeces_a` are reversed so that in the `iAs` for loop, the smaller index is kept (this is more apparent when doing the walkthrough below.)
2. As far as I can tell, the `iAs` for loop finds the `longest increasing subsequence` of `indeces_A_filtered`.

Thanks!

---

Here's a walkthrough of the algorithm for example `A = "peterparker"` and `B = "spiderman"`

```
     01234567890
A = "peterparker"
B = "spiderman"

indeces_A = {'p':[0,5], 'e':[1,3,9], 't':[2], 'r':[4,7,10], 'a':[6], 'k':[8]}

# after reverse
indeces_A = {'p':[5,0], 'e':[9,3,1], 't':[2], 'r':[10,7,4], 'a':[6], 'k':[8]}

#                     -p-  --e--  ---r--  a
indeces_A_filtered = [5,0, 9,3,1, 10,7,4, 6]

# the `iAs` loop

iA = 5
j = 0
iAs = [5]

iA = 0
j = 0
iAs = [0]

iA = 9
j = 1
iAs = [0,9]

iA = 3
j = 1
iAs = [0,3]

iA = 1
j = 1
iAs = [0,1]

iA = 10
j = 2
iAs = [0,1,10]

iA = 7
j = 2
iAs = [0,1,7]

iA = 4
j = 2
iAs = [0,1,4]

iA = 6
j = 3
iAs = [0,1,4,6] # corresponds to indices of A that spell out "pera", the LCS

return len(iAs) # 4, the length of the LCS
```

Comment: Is this O(m log m) for two identical strings made of a single repeated letter?

Comment: @גלעדברקן In that case where `A = B = ch*m` for some char `ch`, `indeces_A_filtered` would be `[rev * m]` where `rev = list(reversed(range(m)))`. I.e. for `m = 4`, `indeces_A_filtered` would equal `[3,2,1,0, 3,2,1,0, 3,2,1,0, 3,2,1,0]`. Therefore, in that case the algorithm would be `O(m*2 log m)`.

In the final iteration, `iAs` would equal `[0,1,2,3]` and `return len(iAs)` which is `4`, which is correct.

Comment: In a case where string `A` has no repeated characters, the overall time complexity would be `O(l log l)` where `l = max(n, m)`.

Comment: What is `m*2` in `O(m*2 log m)` in your comment above? Is that `m times 2` or `m to the power of 2`?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `O(m^2 log m)`, so `m to the power of 2`.

Also, I found another thread which talks about reducing `Longest Common Subsequence` to `Longest Increasing Subsequence`, but mentions `A` must not have repeated elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656050/reducing-longest-common-subsequence-to-longest-increasing-subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing bit here is "patience sorting", whose connection to longest increasing subsequence (LIS) is a bit subtle but well known. The final loop in the code is a bare bones implementation of patience sorting with "the greedy strategy". It does *not*, in general, compute a LIS directly, but rather the length of a LIS.

An easy-enough correctness proof, which includes a sketch of what's needed to reliably compute a LIS too (not just its length), can be found as Lemma 1 early in

> ["Longest Increasing Subsequences: From Patience Sorting to the Baik-Deift-Johansson Theorem"](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/Papers/me86.pdf)
> David Aldous and Persi Diaconis

Comment: Thanks! And I think the reverse step:

`for indeces_a in indeces_A.values(): indeces_a.reverse()`

ensures that, when a letter in `B` matches several positions in `A`, that at most one of those positions is used. E.g. when we have the `"p"` in `B = "spiderman"` matching positions `[0,5]` in `A = "peterparker"`, the reversal ensures that at most one of either `5` or `0` is used in the `LIS` of `indeces_A_filtered`.

Comment: Exactly so! Without reversing, the "filtered" list would be `[0,5, 1,3,9, 4,7,10, 6]`, which has a LIS of length 6 (`[0, 1,3, 4,7,10]`), where, e.g,, the "r" in "spiderman" is counted all three times (at indices 4, 7, and 10) in "peterparker". Reversing ensures - as you say - that at most one instance in each group is counted. It's very clever.

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding the LIS algorithm

```py
def lenLIS(self, nums):
    lis = []
    for num in nums:
        i = bisect.bisect_left(lis, num)
        if i == len(lis):
            lis.append(num) # Append
        else:
            lis[i] = num # Overwrite
    return len(lis)
```

The algorithm above gives us the length of the Longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS) of `nums`, but it doesn't necessarily give us a `LIS` of `nums`. To understand why the algorithm above is correct as well as how to modify it to get a `LIS` of `nums` read on.

I explain by way of examples.

---

#### Example 1

- (taken from [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Papers/me86.pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/Papers/me86.pdf) which was linked by Tim Peters):

```
nums = [7,2,8,1,3,4,10,6,9,5]
lenLIS(nums) == 5
```

The algorithm tells us the length of a `LIS` of `nums` is 5, but how do we get a `LIS` of `nums`.

We represent the history of `lis` as follows (this is explained below):

```
7
2, 8
1, 3, 4, 10
          6, 9
          5
```

The way we represent the history of `lis` is meaningful. To begin with, picture an empty table of rows and colums. We are initially at the top row. In each iteration of the `for num in nums:` loop, we either `Append` `Overwrite` depending the value of `num` and the values of `lis`:

- `Append`: We represent this in the table by writing the appended value (`num`) in the next column over, i.e. at the `i`th column of the current row. The appended value is always greater than all the values in the current row.
- `Overwrite`: If `lis[i]` is already equal to `num`, we don't do anything to the table. Otherwise, we represent this in the table by moving down to the next row and writing the new value (`num`) at the `i`th column of the new row. The new value is always less than all the other values in the colum.

#### Observations:

0. The table can be sparse.
1. Values are inserted in left to right, top to bottom order. Thus, whenever we move up or left in the table, we are moving to earlier elements of `nums`.
2. As we go across a row, the values increase. Thus, a move to the left brings us to a lesser value.
3. Suppose there is a value `v` at `(r, i)`, but not at `(r, i-1)`. This can only happen as the result of an Overwrite. Consider the state of `lis` before the Overwrite. There is a value `v` which must be placed in `lis` and we compute this place as `i = bisect_left(lis, v)`. `i` will be computed s.t. `lis[i-1] < v < lis[i]`. From `v` at (`r, i)`, we can reach `lis[i-1]` in the table by moving left once (to the empty `(r, i-1)`) and then moving up one ore more times until we encounter a value. That value will be `lis[i-1]`.
4. Putting `2.` and `3.` together, we have shown that within the table, we can always move left once and then up zero or more times to reach a lesser value. Denote one application of this movement as `prev`. Furthermore, `1.` tells us that the lesser value we encounter by performing `prev` is a value which occurs earlier in `nums`.

We use `4.` to get `LIS(nums)` from the table. Start at one of the rightmost values of the table, then perform `prev` repeatedly to encouter the other values of `LIS(nums)` in reverse.

Doing this procedure on the example, we start at `9`. Applying `prev` once, we get `6`. A second time, we get `4`, then `3` then `1`. Indeed `[1,3,4,6,9]` is one of the `LIS` of `nums`.

---

#### Example 2:

```
nums = [2,7,10,14,25,5,6,5,10,20,1,22,4,12,7,11,9,25]
lenLIS(nums)
```

The history of `lis`:

```
2, 7, 10, 14, 25
   5,  6  10, 20
1                22
   4          12
       7      11
           9     25
```

So `lenLIS(nums) == 6` is `len(LIS(nums)`. Let's find `LIS(nums)`:

Again, start at one of the rightmost values on the table: `22`. Applying `prev` once, we get `20`. A second time, we get `10`, then `6`, then `5`, then `2`. So `[2,5,6,10,20,22]` is an `LIS` of `nums`.

We could have started at the other rightmost values: `25`. Applying `prev` once, we get `11`. A second time, we get `10`, then `6`, then `5`, then `2`. So `[2,5,6,10,11,25]` is another valid `LIS` of `nums`.

---

This explanation is similar to the one in [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Papers/me86.pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/Papers/me86.pdf), but I found it easier to understand for myself and just wanted to share it in case it was useful to someone else.